# Is there another way to do this in phpmyadmin without repeating customerid?

Tags: phpmyadmin

SELECT * FROM contacttbl WHERE (customerid = 3 OR customerid = 9 OR customerid = 133 OR customerid = 333)

I want to do this in phpmyadmin in the SQL box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in () this mysql function is use to finy any of rows of a table whos specified column is any of this list inside ()

```
select * from contacttbl where customerid in(3, 9, 133, 333)
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. Thanks.